# Spotipy exception

Tags: python, except, spotipy

I have recently been working on a project with spotify API. I am new to relatively programming, so I'm not too sure what to do with this exception. In my program, when you paste a private spotify playlist link, you get an error message which I will paste below. The problem is, I need to except this error message as the entire program crashes if I don't.

Error code:

```
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/*playlist link*/tracks with Params: {'limit': 100, 'offset': 0, 'fields': None, 'market': None, 'additional_types': 'track'} returned 404 due to Not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\spotipy\client.py", line 269, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "path\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/*playlist link*/tracks?limit=100&offset=0&additional_types=track

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\program.py"", line 207, in program
    tracks = session.playlist_tracks(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\spotipy\client.py", line 681, in playlist_tracks
    return self.playlist_items(playlist_id, fields, limit, offset,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\spotipy\client.py", line 705, in playlist_items
    return self._get(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\spotipy\client.py", line 321, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\spotipy\client.py", line 291, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/*playlist link*/tracks?limit=100&offset=0&additional_types=track:
Not found., reason: None
```

I have tried excepting `spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException` and `requests.exceptions.HTTPError`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated `playlist_tracks()`. You should use [`playlist_items()`](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.playlist_items) instead.

Comment: Thank you, I found out where the issue was. I was typing the exception in the wrong place. Thanks for the answer :)